# Unhandled exception executing command in SPIGOT plugin

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to write a plugin to sethome myself but when I issue the `/sethome` command it always errors.

```
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'sethome' in plugin setHome v1.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:763) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1788) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.c(PlayerConnection.java:1631) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1584) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:47) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.bb(MinecraftServer.java:942) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:935) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:919) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:851) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.t2o0n321.setHome.command.sethome.onCommand(sethome.java:33) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[spigot-1.16.5.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
        ... 19 more
```

Here is my code(sethome.java):

```java
package com.t2o0n321.setHome.command;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import com.t2o0n321.setHome.config.config;
import com.t2o0n321.setHome.utils.utils;

public class sethome implements CommandExecutor {

    private static int max_home_amount = 2;

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd,String label,String args[]){
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(!(player instanceof Player)){
            Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(utils.chat("&c[setHome] Only player can issue commands !"));
            return true;
        }
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sethome")){
            if(args.length == 1){
                // init player data
                config.reload();
                // get player info
                String path = player.getName();
                int home_amount = 0;
                for(String home : config.get().getConfigurationSection(path).getKeys(false)){
                    home_amount ++;
                }
                if(home_amount < max_home_amount){
                    // record new home data
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    double x = loc.getX();
                    double y = loc.getY();
                    double z = loc.getZ();
                    String w = loc.getWorld().toString();

                    String x_path = player.getName() + "." + args[0] + ".x";
                    String y_path = player.getName() + "." + args[0] + ".y";
                    String z_path = player.getName() + "." + args[0] + ".z";
                    String w_path = player.getName() + "." + args[0] + ".w";

                    config.get().set(x_path,x);
                    config.get().set(y_path,y);
                    config.get().set(z_path,z);
                    config.get().set(w_path,w);

                    config.save();
                }
                else{
                    player.sendMessage(utils.chat("You can only set "+ max_home_amount + " homes !"));
                }
            }
            else{
                player.sendMessage(utils.chat("Usage: /sethome <home>"));
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, it would be great if you could let me know the content in line 33 in sethome.java, I guess the issue is ```NullPointerException```, which is a ```RuntimeException``` (Which does not throw an error during compilation if you didn't handle it). Some method in the Spigot API might return a ```null```, you might have to check carefully before using them.

Comment: line 33 is ``if(home_amount < max_home_amount)``

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are casting sender to Player before knowing if they actually are. Swap order of these:
put `Player player = (Player) sender;` after your `instanceof` check (and check if sender instanceof Player).
Otherwise this will cause `ClassCastException` if console uses this command.

Second, `if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sethome")){` isn't neccesary if you've registered your command in `onEnable` and in plugin.yml

Third of all, [check out naming conventions in Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). Your class `sethome` should be capitalized, and your variables should be "mixed case with a lowercase first letter"

Another one is you don't need to write your own serialization of `Location`, Bukkit can do that for you, [check out this resource](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/serializing-location-objects/).

As for your `NullPointerException`, are you sure this version of the code and the error correspond? Maybe in between you changed something, added or removed a few lines, all I know is it cannot be cause at line 33 as in the error, because both `max_home_amount` and `home_amount` are always non-null (unless you somehow reassigned max_home_amount which i doubt)

Two lines above that `config.get().getConfigurationSection(path).getKeys(false)` could be causing the problem if the config is missing or the section isn't there